# Does callback are received on main thread only?

Tags: c++, multithreading, callback

I am creating a process, which on running create a child thread also.
At some point child thread register callback of another library. 
when i check that callback is invoked on main thread. Can anyone tell me is it expected and post a link related to this.

I did some research but couldn't find.

Comment: We are unable to answer this question. It completely depends on who invokes the callback and how. You need to read the documentation for the library.

Comment: You'd have to consult the documentation of that other library. There is no general, universally applicable rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does callback are received on main thread only?

No. There is no such limitation in general.

Callback is simply a function behind indirection. Whether called through indirection or not, a function is executed in the thread where the function is called. So, if a child thread calls a function, then the execution of that thread proceeds into that function. If main thread calls the the function, then the execution of the main thread proceeds into the function.

If you register a callback for some library, you need to consult the documentation of that library and see if it tells what thread it will use.

Comment: library i am using is just registering my callback function. 
m_callback  = p_userCallbackFunc ;
there was no information related to this in documentation.
anyway I will check more